# How to use repeat method?

Tags: java, android, phone-call

I have a Method that makes a phone call. The number and delay comes from strings in two edit text box's.  It works fine. But, i would like to put it in a loop so that it does the same this a number of times before it ends.

My code is -

```
public void makeCall(View view) {

             //create handler for phone call

         Handler delayedCallHandler = new Handler() {
              public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                String num = (String) msg.obj;

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(num));
                startActivity(intent);
              }
            };


            //Grabs milli seconds count from edit text box

               EditText edit_seconds = (EditText)
                    findViewById(R.id.seconds);
               CharSequence edit_seconds_value =
                    edit_seconds.getText();

               int secondz = Integer.parseInt(edit_seconds_value.toString());                    

            // Grabs TXT Char from MSISDN edit text box and converts to edit_text_value
            EditText edit_text = (EditText)
                    findViewById(R.id.msisdn);
               CharSequence edit_text_value =
                    edit_text.getText();

            //Delay phone call

            delayedCallHandler.sendMessageDelayed(
                    delayedCallHandler.obtainMessage(0, "tel:" + edit_text_value), // msg.obj = the number to call
                    secondz); // 50 seconds

            // Toast Popup when call set button pressed

            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "You have now set the call for " + edit_seconds_value + "milliseconds" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
            toast.show();  

    }
```

Comment: Which is the function??
Question is not quite clear.

Comment: @Raheel I would like the method to repeat 5 times with a 5 minutes delay between.

Comment: Whats with all the down votes? A little harsh I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch the CALL activity with `startactivityForResult()`. Then in the `OnActivtyResult` send a delayed message to start the next CALL.

```
@Override
void onActivityResult(...) {
   ....
   if (count <= NUMBER_OF_CALLS) {
       delayedCallHandler.sendMessageDelayed(
                    delayedCallHandler.obtainMessage(0, "tel:" + edit_text_value), // msg.obj = the number to call
                    secondz); // 50 seconds
       count++;
   }
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple, You can use `Thread` Class, `TimerTask` Class or `AlarmManager` Class for it. A Sleep Time will be require in Thread and TimerTask Class.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any chance you could provide a code example? I'm new to android/java. Thanks

Comment: Sure, you can visit www.java2.com for it.

Comment: Sorry, but i dont want to do spoon feeding , if you will fail from above Java2s.com, i will surely help you :). But try your self first, Java2s.com is very good and easy, I also learnt from there.

Comment: well it depends on your self, if you want to learn something new, then you need to take only logic part, development part also try your self,, it will help you a lot in future, telling you from my personal experience dear

Answer (score 0):

Simple. I think.
Ok. Lets say you want it to repeat 10 times.
And that your method is called "method()"

```
//BEFORE YOUR ONCREATE
int count = 1;
//PUT THIS WHEREVER YOU WANT TO CALL YOUR METHOD
while(count<=10){
    method();
    count++;
}
```

Then set up your method() after this (Outside the OnCreate)

```
private void method() {
    //DO ALL YOUR STUFF HERE

}
```

In short, this will create the method called method().

Then it will create an int called count with the value of 1.

Then it will do your method and add 1 to "count"

So "count" will now have the value of 2.

As count is still under 10, it will do the method again..

and again... and again until count=10

It will then stop.

Rename method() to whatever you like and add in what you wanted to do.